# mysql BLOB and TEXT data type difference

Tags: mysql, text, types, blob

What's difference between BLOB and TEXT data type in mysql ? ( except sortable )

Comment: Even if he has frankly I like having the answer on SE; the sites usually load fast and the answers are fairly reliable.

Answer (score 19):

`BLOB` is used for storing binary data, while `TEXT` is used to store large strings.

As stated in the [MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/blob.html):

> `BLOB` values are treated as binary strings (byte strings). They have no
>   character set, and sorting and comparison are based on the numeric
>   values of the bytes in column values. `TEXT` values are treated as
>   nonbinary strings (character strings). They have a character set, and
>   values are sorted and compared based on the collation of the character
>   set.

Answer (score 2):

Mmm google is your friend I guess:

TEXT and CHAR will convert to/from the character set they have associated with time. BLOB and BINARY simply store bytes.

Answer (score -2):

Main difference between BLOB and TEXT: BLOB is casesensetive TEXT.