# zf2 JsonModel() using Blob in doctrine 2 ORM

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am trying to fetch JSON response using JsonModel() in ZF2,

I am getting following error

```
 $dql = "SELECT * FROM \Application\Entity\Message m ";

           $resultSet = $objectManager->createQuery($dql)
                    ->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);


$result = new JsonModel($resultSet);
```

I am getting following warning

```
Warning: json_encode(): type is unsupported, encoded as null in....
```

If I exclude blob type field from selection it works fine.

Why JsonModel does not work with blob type fields?
Is there any alternative I can use in doctrine?

Comment: You code is Vague at the moment in Above $resultSet dont explain anything regarding "blob", more over "json_encode" is no where called in the above code so i cant see why there is warning there

Answer (score 0):

[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function only works with UTF-8 encoded data.
[blob](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) is Binary data type. 
There is difference between [blob(binary) and text data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828849/mysql-blob-and-text-data-type-difference)

You might need to convert your binary data into string before encoding data into json. 
There are different ways to do it.

1. [method1 in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948174/how-do-i-convert-from-blob-to-text-in-mysql)
2. [method2 in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769774/when-querying-blob-from-db-how-do-i-convert-the-blob-to-text-in-my-query)